# Div showing multiple times and button still disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are 2 input fields, one for writing a new password and one to confirm the password written in the new password field, I am trying to make it that a div showing `please enter the password above` is shown below the confirm password textbox and the submit button is disabled when the value is not equal to the new password field's value, but when it is correct remove the error div  and enable the submit button, but it doesn't enable the submit button and it doesn't remove the error div, it also shows the error div multiple times, Please what's my error

```
......


    <label for="new-password" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">New Password</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="new-password" type="password" class="form-control new-p" name="new-password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="new-password-confirm" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Confirm    New Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="new-password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control confirm" name="new-password_confirmation" required>
                <div class='row' id="edit-profile-buttons">
                    <button type='submit' id="editUser" name="editUser">Change Password</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </form>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.confirm').on('change', function (e) {
           var test = $('.new-p').val();
            if ((e.target.value ===  test) && e.target.value != '' ){
                $(".confirm").parent().next(".error").remove(); 
                $("#editUser").removeAttr("disabled");
            }else
                alert(e.target.value);
            $(".confirm").parent().after("<div class='error' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter the password you typed above</div>");
            $("#editUser").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Use `$("#editUser").prop("disabled", false);` to enable and `$("#editUser").prop("disabled", true);`to disable. It's a boolean property...

Comment: It didn't work, I've tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your else statement is missing brackets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.confirm').on('change', function (e) {
                var test = $('.new-p').val();
                if ((e.target.value === test) && e.target.value != '') {
                    debugger;
                    $(".confirm").parent().next(".error").remove();
                    $("#editUser").removeAttr("disabled");
                } else { //else do this whole thing
                    alert(e.target.value);
                $(".confirm").parent().after("<div class='error' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter the password you typed above</div>");
                    $("#editUser").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label for="new-password" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">New Password</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="new-password" type="password" class="form-control new-p" name="new-password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="new-password-confirm" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Confirm New Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="new-password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control confirm" 
                       name="new-password_confirmation" required>
                <div class='row' id="edit-profile-buttons">
                    <button type='submit' id="editUser" name="editUser">Change Password</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly.... The `else` isn't between `{` and `}`... It works with it. But change `.attr()` to `.prop()` anyway for a better code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple hints, to show you the path to your solution:

1. Try using the `input` event instead of `change`
2. Pull out your application state into a separate object, and compare using that.
3. Make the error message a persistent DOM element, that is toggled on or off based on the password comparison.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var state = {
    p1: "",
    p2: ""
  };
  
  $('#error').hide();
  $('#new-password').on('input', enter_value.bind(null, "p1"));
  $('#new-password-confirm').on('input', enter_value.bind(null, "p2"));
  
  function enter_value(value_name, event) {
    var new_value = event.target.value;
    state[value_name] = new_value;
    compare_values();
  }
  
  function compare_values() {
    if (state.p1 !== state.p2) {
      $('#error').show();
      $("#editUser").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      return;
    }
    $('#error').hide();
    $("#editUser").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="new-password" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">New Password</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="new-password" type="password" class="form-control new-p" name="new-password" required></div>
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="new-password-confirm" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Confirm    New Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input id="new-password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control confirm" name="new-password_confirmation" required>
<div class='row' id="edit-profile-buttons">
<button type='submit' id="editUser" name="editUser">Change Password</button>
<div id='error' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter the password you typed above</div>
</div></form>
```